# Can't get NetBeans syntax highlighting with boost library

Tags: c++, boost, netbeans, syntax, highlighting

With NetBeans (v. 6.9.1) I cannot get syntax highlighting for the Boost library, i.e. all stuff present in Boost is not recognised. However the project is built correctly.

I already set the paths in: NetBeans > Preferences > C/C++ > Code Assistance > C++ Compiler.
Here I added the `/usr/local/include` path.

The Boost headers are in `/usr/local/include/boost`, so if in my code I use something like:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
```

the include file should be found by the editor (as it is found by the compiler).

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

OS: MacOS X 10.6.4

P.S.: I got this problem after updating Boost to the latest version (1.44.0); previously it worked fine (with v. 1.41.0); I must have done something differently now, and I do not remember the details of what I did last time.

P.S.2: Now I can get to the include files right clicking on the #include directive. However syntax highlighting for Boost items does not work, yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the same problem you are having but I find that Netbeans frequently gets confused about syntax highlighting and includes. I'm not entirely sure what triggers it but I've found that it can often be cleared up by shutting down Netbeans and deleting the cache directory `~\.netbeans\6.9\var\cache`.